# Compute the probability that at least one of the angles of the triangle $ABC$ exceeds $x\pi$

Tags: self-study, random-variable

As part of self-study, I am trying to solve the following problem from *Grimmett G. Stirzaker, D. (2001). Probability and Random Processes. Oxford University Press.*

> **Let $A,B,C$ be three points, chosen independently and uniformly at random on the circumference of a circle. Let $b(x)$ be the probability that at least one of the angles of the triangle $ABC$ exceeds $x\pi$. Show that
> $$
> b(x)= 1-(3x-1)^2\ \ \ \ \  \mbox{if}\ \ \frac{1}{3}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2};\\   
> b(x)= 3(1-x)^2  \ \ \ \ \  \mbox{if}\  \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1.
> $$**

**My attempt.**

Here is what I have tried so far.

Without loss of generality, we assume the circle is unit circle.
Let $A=(1,0),\ B=(1,\theta), $ and $C=(1,\phi)$ where $0<\theta<\phi<2\pi$. It is obvious that the joint density function $f(\theta,\phi)=(2\pi^2)^{-1}$ with $0<\theta<\phi<2\pi.$ Moreover, we have
$$
\angle A=\frac{1}{2}(\phi-\theta),\ \ \angle B=\pi-\frac{\phi}{2},\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ 
\angle C=\frac{1}{2}\theta.
$$
First, consider $x\in [1/3,1/2]$. I tried to compute the probability that all angles are less than $x\pi$ as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\theta \leq x\pi,\ \ \frac{1}{2}(\phi-\theta)\leq x\pi,\ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \pi-\frac{1}{2}\phi\leq x\pi.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\theta \in [0,2x\pi],\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ \phi\in [2(1-x)\pi,2x\pi+\theta]. 
$$
Hence,
$$
\int_{0}^{2x\pi}\int_{2(1-x)\pi}^{2x\pi+\theta}\frac{1}{2\pi^2}d\phi d\theta =\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{2x\pi} [2x\pi+\theta-2\pi+2x\pi]d\theta = \\
\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{2x\pi} [2\pi(2x-1)+\theta]d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}[(2\pi)(2x-1)(2x\pi)+2x^2\pi^2] =5x^2-2x. 
$$
Thus, I obtain $b(x)=1-(5x^2-2x)=-5x^2+2x+1.$ The result is much different to the the goal.

For the case $x\in [1/2,1].$ I analyzed as follows:

It is obvious that $\angle C=1/2\theta $ is impossible exceed $x\pi$, so we only need to consider angle $B$ and angle $A$.
$$
\angle B>x\pi \Rightarrow \pi-\frac{1}{2}\phi>x\pi \Rightarrow \phi <2\pi(1-x). 
$$

Thus, we have $\angle B>x\pi\ \ $   if and only if $\ \ \phi\in [0,2\pi(1-x)]$ and $\theta\in [0,\phi].$
$$
\angle A>x\pi \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(\phi-\theta) >x\pi \Rightarrow \phi>2x\pi+\theta. 
$$
On the other hand, $\angle C\leq x\pi$, and hence $\theta\leq 2x\pi.$

Thus, we have $\angle A>x\pi \ \ $ if and only if $\ \ \phi\in [2x\pi+\theta,2\pi]$ and $\theta\in [0,2x\pi].$
For this case, $x\in [1/2,1]$, I also got the the different $b(x)$.

*In both cases, I am unable to derive the answer that I am required to show. I would appreciate if members of the community were to assist me in discerning where I have erred.*

Comment: We are happy to address specific questions, but we don't operate as a homework-checking service.  Please visit our [help] for more information about how to use this site effectively.

Comment: @whuber This is not a homework question, this from the book probabilty and random process by Grimmett & Stirzaker. I am trying to solve this for self learning.

Comment: That's what we mean by homework.  We don't care whether you are taking courses, exams, etc.  Homework problems are distinguished by their routine nature and their pedagogical aims.  *That's* why we treat them differently.

Comment: @Lureboar. I have edited your question to more accurately reflect what I think you were trying to ask. Does the edited question not deviate too greatly from what you had in mind? Because other than a minor point about the articulation of your question, this seems an acceptable self-study question because you've [*"made a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first*"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: yes @microhaus . It does not deviate .

Comment: You go awry at the outset: neither $B$ nor $C$ lie on the unit circle and $f$ is not a valid joint density function (it does not integrate to unity).  //  This problem has an elementary solution requiring only Euclidean geometry.  Exploit the symmetry (the angles may be arbitrarily permuted) to construct the PDF and integrate the PDF using formulas for areas of triangles.